# Ajax Scrolling Page Repeat Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, scroll, asp.net-ajax

I am using asp.net mvc and ajax for creating a timeline. With scroll, the new page is triggered and append. If scrolling slowly no problem, the correct number of records is coming. But, if it scrolling fast, records are appended several times. How can I solve this problem?

```
var CurrentPage = 1;
var isPageLoad = true;



$(window).scroll(function () {               
     if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 80) {            
         if (isPageLoad) {
             $("#load").show();
             $.ajax({
                 url: '/GetInitialDespatch',
                 data: { page: CurrentPage },
                 success: function (data) {
                     $("#timeline").append(data);
                     CurrentPage++;
                     $("#load").hide();                        
                     if ($.trim(data) == '') {
                         isPageLoad = false;
                      }                        
                 }
             });
         }
     }
 });
```

Comment: Set `isPageLoad = false;` immediately after `if (isPageLoad) {` so no further ajax calls are made (ajax is async and your not setting it to false until the ajax call is complete which means more calls can be made in the meantime)

Comment: Its work thanks a lot.